# How many memory locations will it take to have a string concatenation?

Tags: java, string, memory-management, stringbuilder

How many memory locations will it take to have a string concatenation?

```
String myStringVariable = "Hello";
```

In following two statements :

```
String s = "ABC" + "Hello" + "DEF";
```

and

```
String s = "ABC";
s = s + "Hello";
s = s + "DEF";
```

and

```
String s = "ABC" + myStringVariable + "DEF";
```

Which will consume more memory? In which of the case StringBuilder is useful to the most?

Comment: The first one is definitely amenable to constant-folding. The second one should be as well.

Comment: Correction: the second example will not, in fact, be constant-folded. (Also: did you HAVE to change the samples after you received answers?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First statement will be converted by compiler into `String s = "ABCDEF";` so there will be no concatination

Second statement will be converted by compiler into this code (or something like this)

```
    String s = "ABC";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    sb.append("DEF");
    s = sb.toString();
```

Comment: what JVM Vendor/Version supports this resolution? Particularly the second one (obviously at least >=1.5)?

Comment: First case behaviour is defined by JLS - compile time constant. Second >= 1.5 for sure since StringBuilder was introduced in 1.5

Comment: @Yaneeve: Before 1.5, `StringBuffer` was used the same way `StringBuilder` is used today. This feature exists since the very first version.

Comment: @Yaneeve I believe there was a version that, for the second OP's sample, would have created two `StringBuffer`s. However it's old enough to be irrelevant. Concatenation was always done using `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` I believe, there is no "native" concatenation operation in the JDK. (Although an alternative JDK is free to compile string concatenation to something else as long as it works.)

Comment: OK, so the first case is defined by the JLS, but for the second, I gather, from your comments that it is hotspot's behavior, does any other vendor do it likewise?

Comment: I cannot verify it but it is quite logical to use StringBuilder for concatination because it is faster than the other option - String.concat

Comment: @Yaneeve: It’s the compiler, i.e. javac, creating the code using a `StringBuilder`. This has nothing to do with HotSpot.

Comment: @Yaneeve Are you really using a JVM from some other vendor than Oracle? If you are, you can verify it yourself. If you aren't, then why would you care? If you're curious you can still check yourself by compiling with each alternative JDK and decompiling with `javap`.

Comment: It seems, the question has been edited after this answer has been written. The “second example”, to which this answer refers, does not exist anymore. The current second example is `String s = "ABC" + "Hello" + "DEF";`, which will be compiled to `String s = "ABCHelloDEF";`.

Answer (score 3):

`StringBuilder` will be helpful in neither case, as written - the compiler will reuse the same `StringBuilder` instance when possible. It's *marginally* helpful when you're adding strings in a loop. (I say "marginally" because most of the time you're not really adding *that* many strings, nor are they *that* long. The difference will show up in microbenchmarks but your program isn't one, unless you're writing a templating engine or something like that.)

Creating garbage `StringBuilder`s doesn't "waste memory" as much as cause GC pressure. A generational scavenger GC such as Java's is, in fact, designed to make creating lots of very short-lived garbage objects efficient. I wouldn't worry about it unless you're actually spending too much time in GC.

Copying the `String` contents into the `StringBuilder`s repeatedly is also wasteful, but once again, unlikely to make a significant impact outside a loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "ABC" + "DEF";
```

That resolved at compile time and no `StringBuilder` used to concat.

and

```
String s = "ABC";
s = s + "DEF";
```

In this case `StringBuilder(string...).toString()` to resolve the `String` at run time.

So you need to use `StringBuilder`, In your case it's negligible performance difference.

do not use much concatenation's with "+", cannot do much harm in lesser amount of concatenations. If you are dealing with larger amount prefer to use StringBuilder with append method.

You can see the difference if you are concatenating String's in Large extent with `+`, then go for `StringBuilder` append.

Answer (score 2):

I create class `Main`:

```
public class Main {
    public String foo() {
        String s = "ABC" + "DEF";
        return s;
    }
    public String foo1() {
        String s = "ABC";
        s = s + "DEF";
        return s;
    }
}
```

and decompile it:

```
public java.lang.String foo();
Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
Code:
   0: ldc           #2                  // String ABCDEF
   2: astore_1
   3: aload_1
   4: areturn

public java.lang.String foo1();
Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
Code:
   0: ldc           #3                  // String ABC
   2: astore_1
   3: new           #4                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
   6: dup
   7: invokespecial #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
  10: aload_1
  11: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  14: ldc           #7                  // String DEF
  16: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  19: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
  22: astore_1
  23: aload_1
  24: areturn
```

Method `foo` make concatenation string compile-time but method `foo1` concatenate string at run-time and use `StringBuilder`.

**First** example use less memory.

I use Oracle JDK 1.7_45 with default properties.

Answer (score 1):

> Which will consume more memory?

The java specification [**`15.8.1 String Concatenation Operator +:`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)

> **The String object is newly created (§12.5) unless the expression is a
>   compile-time constant expression** (§15.28).
>
> **An implementation may choose to perform conversion and concatenation
>   in one step to avoid creating and then discarding an intermediate
>   String object.** To increase the performance of repeated string
>   concatenation, a Java compiler may use the StringBuffer class or a
>   similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate String objects
>   that are created by evaluation of an expression.

- First statement,

  ```
   String s = "ABC" + "Hello" + "DEF";
  ```

  This expression is a compile-time constant expression. Will be done in one step. No object is created in run-time.
- Second statement:

  ```
    String s = "ABC";
    s = s + "Hello";
    s = s + "DEF";
  ```

  this statement will create a new string containing `"ABCHELLO"`.  Third statement will create a new string containing `"ABCHELLODEF"`. This string concatenation will happen using a `StringBuilder`.
- Third statement

  ```
  String s = "ABC" + myStringVariable + "DEF";
  ```

  unlike the first statement, this statement Will create one new instance at run-time as it is not a **compile-time constant expression.**

But using `StringBuilder` for concatenating such three string won't result in performance gain, unless you are working with number of strings with which counting does matter.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder is useful when you want to play with string. dynamically creating string by combining string. it will occupy in one object only.

if you use string every time it any concatenation will create new object in memory.

Comment: Trivial string concatenation compiles down to a `StringBuilder` anyway so there's no difference.