# Do different Java Compilers (where the vendor is different) produce different bytecode

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javac, bytecode

**Given the same major version, say Java 7, do different Java Compilers (e.g., Oracle's hotspot, JRockit, or IBM's J9 etc...) compile a given java source code file into the same bytcode?**

Scanning the [Java 7 language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html) it would seem that what is being discussed is the semantics of the language and not the transformation of the code into bytecode.

This question is not the same as do different major.minor versions for a given vendor produce the same bytecode. That question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012978/do-different-jdk-updates-produce-different-java-byte-code) - with a *could be*.

From the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14985246/101715) to [Is the creation of Java class files deterministic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984984/is-the-creation-of-java-class-files-deterministic) and a comment to that answer that refers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14267348/101715) along side two answers to the major.minor question above [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3012991/101715) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3013009/101715), I gather that the answer to my question is **YES**.

Excerpts for the above are:

> The JLS leaves many implementation details to vary from one
>   implementation to another.

and

> However the JLS does not specify a 1:1 mapping from source code to the
>   generated byte code, so you should not rely on the exact same byte
>   code to be generated.

Yet a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20262139/101715) implies differently:

> It’s the compiler, i.e. javac, creating the code using a
>   BLAH BLAH BLAH. This has nothing to do with HotSpot.

It implies that given a code X all javac implementations (same version/different vendors) must produce the same Y bytecode.

I cannot see how that is so, but I am unable to verify that it is not (or that what I think, see above) is correct.

Can a definitive answer be given?

Comment: Ingos answer is correct. I want to add that I do not think that the comment concerning HotSpot and the compiler meant what you describe. The commentator wanted to express that it is *javac* who adds the `StringBuilder` to the byte code while the HotSpot run time only interprets/compiles this byte code. The byte code created by *javac* changed quite a lot over the years and new optimizations were applied from version to version. Also, new byte code instructions were added to the JVMS such that new optimizations could be applied. Even different versions of *javac* produce different byte code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are differences between the compilers and interestingly some of the permitted differences led to problems in the past.

Some differences are small, e.g. some compilers optimize `x=x+1` to produce the same bytecode as `x++`, others don’t.

Others can have more impact, e.g. the standard did not specify how to generate the names of synthetic members used to implement inner class access to private members (and similar things) in the past (I don’t know whether it does today). But the algorithm for calculating a default [`serialVersionUID`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html#skip-navbar_bottom) used a hash code over all class members, even synthetic ones.

As a consequence, compiling with `javac` or the first Eclipse versions created classes with incompatible `serialVersionUID`s. Today, Eclipse uses the same name schema for synthetic members as `javac` and issues a warning about missing explicit `serialVersionUID`s in `Serializable` classes by default.

There’s still a lot of freedom and even packing with `pack200` and unpacking may create classes with different byte code than the original classes.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 questions:

1. Are different java compilers free to generate different bytecode for the same source code?
2. Do they actually produce different bytecode for the same source.

The answer to 1 is yes, obviously. For, otherwise, the JLS had to fully specify the bytecode to generate for each and every language construct. But it doesn't.

The answer to 2 I don't know for sure, though I have heard that eclipse compiler generates slightly different code than javac in some cases. Should be easy to verify.

Comment: Concerning your answer to question #1, I can gather from it that it is an intentional feature of the JLS and not due to, say laziness, _right?_

Comment: @Yaneeve Indeed. It is the same thing with all languages that I know of. The Language specification writers take care not to prescribe implementation details. Why should they? In this context, it is interesting to note that the JVM is **not** part of the JLS, but has its own specification.

Answer (score 2):

The comment in question does not actually disagree.  Note that you are mixing up two different things here:  Java bytecode compilers (`javac`) and Java just-in-time compilers (such as HotSpot or J9).  You normally use some javac implementation to translate java source code to java bytecode.

Then you take the bytecode and execute it in a JVM, which uses *another* compiler.

Again, there are two sets of compilers:

1. Bytecode compilers (`.java` to `.class`)
2. Just-in-time compilers as part of Java virtual machines (execute `.class` files)

(**EDIT:** Neither of these are guaranteed to produce identical results (i.e., the same `java` file can yield different `class` files, and the same `class` file can yield different machine code when the JIT is done with it.))

The reason for having two sequential compilation processes is that if you wrap everything into one compiler, you lose two properties:

1. your compiled program will be platform-specific
2. your program will not (easily) be able to perform some of the optimisations and advanced language features (reflection, dynamic class loading) that Java provides.

Comment: If I had mixed up the names (though I don't think so...) - _my bad!_ My question had targeted the javac implementation and not the JVM's JIT implementation...